# Webform uploads / Media

Tags: 7, webforms, media, files

I've run into the following:

User uploads are among the uploads from the admin / editors.

Is there a possibility to show uploaded files from the [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module in a different module than the Media module, or a different directory in the [media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module? The files are already in a different directory on the server, but not in the back-end of drupal.

Any help is much appreciated :-)

Thanks!